# Projection with two attributes with same name

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, projection

I have a projection using Interface, and i need the genre.Id and the movie.Id, but in table it have the same name:

```
public interface MovieProjection {
       
    Long getId();  //Genre Id
    
    Long getId();  //Movie Id
    
    String getName();
    String getTitle();
    String getSynopsis();
    String getImg_url();
    Integer getMovie_Year();
    String getSub_Title();

}
```

SQL:

```
public interface MovieRepository  extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long>{

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = """
            SELECT * 
            FROM  tb_movie
            INNER JOIN  tb_genre ON tb_genre.id = tb_movie.genre_id  
            WHERE (:genreId IS NULL OR tb_genre.id IN :genreId)
                
                """, countQuery = """
                        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT tb_movie.title, tb_movie.Synopsis, tb_genre.name
            FROM  tb_movie
            INNER JOIN  tb_genre ON tb_genre.id = tb_movie.genre_id  
            WHERE (:genreId IS NULL OR tb_genre.id IN :genreId)
            ) AS tb_result
                        """)
        Page<MovieProjection> searchAllPaged(List<Long> genreId, Pageable pageable);
  
}
```

I tried using @Value but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the query you have to rename the fields manually.

For example

```
public interface MovieProjection {
       
    Long getGenreId();  //Genre Id
    
    Long getMovieId();  //Movie Id
    
    String getMovieName();
    String getMovieTitle();
    ....
}
```

and

```
SELECT * 
            FROM  tb_movie
            INNER JOIN  tb_genre ON tb_genre.id = tb_movie.genre_id  
            WHERE (:genreId IS NULL OR tb_genre.id IN :genreId)
```

to

```
SELECT  tbm.id as movieId,
tmb.name as movieName,
tmb.title as movieTitle,
tbg.id as genreId
            FROM  tb_movie tbm
            INNER JOIN  tb_genre tbg ON tbg.id = tbm.genre_id  
            WHERE (:genreId IS NULL OR tb_genre.id IN :genreId)
```